# this.url is not a function

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

In Nightwatch, I'm trying to write a command for checking the url of the current page.

When I write this directly in the test file, it looks like this:

```
browser.url(function (result) {
    browser.assert.equal(result.value,expectedPageUrl);
});
```

This works perfectly, returns expected results. However, when I try to move it into the pageObject file and modify it like this:

```
checkUrl: function (expectedUrl) {
    var _this= this;
    this.url(function (result) {
        _this.assert.equal(result.value,expectedUrl);
    });
}
```

this returns the error

> TypeError: this.url is not a function

What am I missing here?

Comment: should it be this.browser.url ? in the test

Comment: Does the pageObject has a browser property? Maybe it should be this.browser.url(...)

Comment: i think browser is not defined in the page object. i tried as you suggested, i get " TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined".

Comment: How is `checkUrl` called? What `this` refers to depends on how a function is called. Whatever `this` is, it doesn't have a `url` property.

Comment: i call it like this:  module.exports = {'test1' : function (browser) { var myPage = browser.page.myPageObject(); myPage.checkUrl (url) }};

Comment: Then `this` will refer to `myPage`. Does `myPage` have a `url` property?

Comment: no, it doesn't. how can i make it have it? probably at that point ' this' is not refering to the browser yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is most probably because the '*url*' is not defined in your second function, within the this object.

One way to solve it would be to try passing in that browser object as a parameter in your *checkUrl* function. and then to call it:

```
checkUrl: function (browser, expectedUrl) {  
    browser.url(function (result) {
        _this.assert.equal(result.value,expectedUrl);
    });
}
```

Comment: this worked! never thought i could pass the whole browser as a parameter to a function! thanks!

Comment: can it cause any problems if i pass the 'browser' as a parameter?